# While taking a screenshot on Macbook Pro, my iPhone also flashes

Tags: iphone, mac

My Mac and iPhone are using same Apple ID, but I have disabled iCloud for most sync features.

What feature could have enabled this screenshot sharing?
How do I disable it?

Comment: Try turning off handoff. Also see Xcode being a possible reason https://www.ilounge.com/index.php/tips/comments/capturing-ios-and-tvos-screenshots-using-your-mac

Comment: Please post an answer with the steps to fix it.